# How to create a file in Documents Directory with custom extension?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to create a file with custom extension (.tk) that will be created from a NSDictionary. How do I do this?

My goal is to create this file and then send it over AirDrop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to take advantage of the fact that the NSDictionary conforms to NSCoding/NSSecureCoding and serialize it:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:networkData];
[archiver encodeObject:self.dictionary forKey:@"dict"];
[archiver finishEncoding];

if ([data length]) {
    if (![data writeToURL:URL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]) {
        NSAssert(NO, @"failed to write dictionary to disk: %@", error);
    }
} else {
    NSAssert(NO, @"failed to serialize dictionary", self);
}
```